# Create "default" value for constructor function with prototype?

Tags: javascript

Ive created a constructor function called Cat. `var fluffy` is an instance of this.

Ive attempted to set a the default value for the breed to be tabby. However when I log out fluffy breed is undefined.

```
'use strict';

function Cat(name, age, breed) {
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age,
  this.breed = breed
}

Cat.prototype.breed = "tabby";

var fluffy = new Cat ("Fluffy the 3rd", "4 years");

console.log(fluffy);
```

Console result:

```
Object { name: "Fluffy the 3rd", age: "4 years", breed: undefined }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have not passed a value to your `breed` argument, so it's overwriting `Cat.prototype.breed = 'tabby'` with `this.breed =` argument value which is `undefined`.

Maybe you want to do this:

```js
'use strict';

function Cat(name, age, breed) {
  this.name = name; this.age = age;
  if(breed || breed === 0)this.breed = breed;
}

Cat.prototype.breed = 'tabby';

var fluffy = new Cat('Fluffy the 3rd', '4 years');

console.log(fluffy);
```

Comment: `if(breed || breed === 0)`? Surely you mean `if (typeof breed != 'undefined')` ? Why would *breed* be set to 0?

Comment: No, I'm allowing you to have a breed as the number 0, just not anything else falsey. If someone passes zero to that parameter, I would think they want that, in this case.

Comment: Testing against undefined means it can be any value other than undefined (which may or may not suit).

Comment: Yeah, that's just a falsey, besides zero, test. Any String, or not negative number, or Object will pass that test. You may want to use `if(breed && typeof breed === 'string')` or something.

Comment: Exactly. The OP just wants to test whether a value was supplied, so testing against undefined seems most appropriate (though it can't discriminate between a value not being supplied and being passed *undefined* explicitly).

Comment: In Javascript you shouldn't discriminate between a value not being supplied and being supplied as `undefined`, and you can't: that's the entire point of `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Javascript do not require that you pass in the exact set of arguments that you define the function with. So this is fine:

```
function f() {
     console.log(arguments); // prints "1 2 3"
}

f(1, 2, 3);
```

And so is this:

```
function g(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b, c); // prints "undefined undefined undefined"
}
g();
```

If you pass *more* arguments than there are parameters (the first case), they are only accessible through the `arguments` array.

If you pass *fewer* arguments than there are parameters (the second case, and your case in your question), those parameters will be `undefined` inside the function.

That is why you get `breed: undefined`: when you call `Cat`, you aren't passing a breed, and unlike in most languages, Javascript has not given you an error, it has just bound the `breed` parameter to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not passing a breed argument to the Cat constructor, JavaScript treats `breed` as `undefined` inside the constructor function. The issue is that assigning `undefined` to `this.breed` has a subtly different effect than not assigning it at all.

To see the difference, try using `delete` to remove the property from the `fluffy` object:

```
'use strict';

function Cat(name, age, breed) {
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age,
  this.breed = breed
}

Cat.prototype.breed = "tabby";

var fluffy = new Cat ("Fluffy the 3rd", "4 years");
console.log(fluffy.breed); // logs "undefined"

delete fluffy.breed;
console.log(fluffy.breed); // logs "tabby"
```

To do this with a prototype you would need to use if/then logic in the constructor:

```
function Cat(name, age, breed) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  if (breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
  }
}
```

It might be easiest to assign the default in the constructor, though.

```
function Cat(name, age, breed) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.breed = breed || 'tabby';
}
```

(Note that this won't allow `this.breed` to be falsey values like "" or 0, so be conscious of the range of values that you want to allow.)